# How does linux excutables work in vmware player?

Tags: linux, windows, vmware

The .exe files won't directly run on Linux and a Linux executable won't directly run on Windows. But we install VMware in windows we can run both the files on same hardware and architecture. How do the executables work ??

Comment: It's up to the OS to interpret the executable file.  Windows understands how to execute PE files (EXE, DLL, etc.), Linux understands ELF files. In the end the same instruction set is used on the processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a deeper picture you can give it a look to the wikipedia about VMware Workstation <sup>[[1](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation)]</sup> and about the Virtual Machine Monitor <sup>[[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)]</sup>.

> VMware Workstation can save the state of a virtual machine (a "snapshot") at any instant. These snapshots can later be restored, effectively returning the virtual machine to the saved state.

So you can run at the same time more than one operative system each with its own executable.
It is like a *"Super Operative System"* that continuously switches among each single virtual machine.
**The different executable can work on the top of the system they were compiled for**, and if all it is done correctly they will not notice any difference.

**Some words more**

In general you have different ways to set a machine allowing to work to executables compiled for different different operative systems or different architectures:

- You can install more than a single operating system, e.g. Windows and Linux, at the same time.
  **At boot time you choose** with which operating system to work.
  **`(+)`** You will have full functionality and speed but one for time.
  **`(-)`** This implies to use the space needed for each installation on the drives.
- You can have an **emulator**, a program that translates (*"emulates"*) every single machine instruction, maybe allowing to run a 64bit code on a 32bit machine. E.g. `bochs` <sup>[[2](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)]</sup> or the famous `mame`<sup>[[3](http://mamedev.org/)]</sup> able to emulate many thousands of classic arcade video games and hardware on a modern computer.
  **`(+)`** You will probably save space on the drives.
  **`(-)`** You will run slowly because you need to translate each instruction.
- You can have a **compatibility layer** as `wine`  <sup>[[4](http://www.winehq.org)]</sup> (in origin an acronym for "Wine Is Not an Emulator"), *capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, Mac OSX, & BSD, **translating the Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly.***
  **`(+)`** Faster than the previous
  **`(-)`** Not always compatible
- You can install a **Virtual Machine Monitor, VMM, of type II** <sup>[[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)]</sup>. This **virtualization software**, as the open source VirtualBox <sup>[[5](http://www.virtualbox.org/)]</sup>, will allow to install a whole unmodified operating system on which the relative executables will run. The so called **virtual machine will run hosted** by your original operative system (see the figure below).

  > ... a kind of virtualization that allows an unmodified operating system with all of its installed software to run in a special environment, **on top of your existing operating system.** This environment, called a "virtual machine", is created by the virtualization software by intercepting access to certain hardware components and certain features <sup>[[5](http://www.virtualbox.org/)]</sup>.

  VMM of Type I,II <sup>[[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)]</sup>:   [image: hypervisors of type I and II]
- Last but not least, an **hypervisor of the type I** <sup>[[6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)]</sup>, or **virtual machine monitor** (VMM), *a piece of computer software, firmware or hardware that creates and runs virtual machines*. This time it will run directly on the hardware and the Operative System will be as *one of its programs*. See the figure above.

  > **It runs directly on the host's hardware to control the hardware and to manage guest operating systems.** For this reason, they are sometimes called bare metal hypervisors. A guest operating system runs as a process on the host.

**Conclusion**
Each executable is compiled for one operating system through which it has to communicate with the hardware. Different instruction, libraries, policies... for this reason an executable of Windows usually will not run under Linux and *vice versa*, but as you can see there are many ways to take care of this *language translation*, adding a layer of a different kind, so that the program can be unaware.

<sup>**Note:** Some assembler program needed direct access to memory and interrupts <sup>[[7](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/FaultHandling/dma_interrupt_handling.htm)]</sup> and they may need a particular care.</sup>